# How to edit tweet styling using node package vue-tweet-embed in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, npm, vue.js

I am working with vue to embed a tweet on a site. I have code that works to generate the tweets in this component and it works when called but I can't get it to style how I want (especially on mobile, its too small). I've tried a few different styling things but none of them edit the tweet. Literally nothing in the .tweet{} styling or the commented code after changed anything. I would like it to fill the width of the phone increase text size on mobile. Help? Thanks!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component-view :id="'891397134662193152'" class="tweet"></component-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'tweets',
    components: {
      'component-view': Tweet
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .tweet {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-size: 600px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
  /*.tweet a {
      font-size: 70px;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 20px;
    }*/

  /*.tweet p.Tweet-text.e-entry-title {
      width:100% !important;
    }*/
</style>
```

Comment: Each question should be self-contained. please copy relevant pieces from the other question to make this more understandable.

Comment: thanks @happymacarts, this is my first time asking a question :) all the relevant info is here, I more just linked that question because it was working with the same plug-in